# How to replace the last character in a string, JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a calculator and got stuck.
I can't figure out how to replace the last character (which is a math symbol).
For example, if a person clicks '+' and then clicks '-', it should not be displayed as '+-'.

I've tried:

- `inputDisplay.textContent = inputDisplay.textContent.replace(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)$/, this.value);`;

> select any of the math operators at the end of the string and replace it with
>   'this.value' (which is also a math symbol). The output is: '1+-/+*'...

- `let lastSymbol = inputDisplay.textContent.slice(-1);
      inputDisplay.textContent = inputDisplay.textContent.replace(lastSymbol, this.value);`

> console.log(lastSymbol) logs math symbols (one at a time), but when I use a .replace() method to replace 'lastSymbol' variable, math symbols are concatenated, not replaced: '1+-+*'...

- `let stringWithoutLastCharacter = inputDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
  inputDisplay.textContent = stringWithoutLastCharacter + this.value;`

> math symbols are also concatenated: '1+-+'...

I don't know how to solve this, so I'm asking for help.
Thanks.

Comment: You only want to replace, if the last character is a operator, right?

Comment: You add operator before, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not the replacement but, adding the current operator before:

```
if (!symbols.includes(this.value) ) {
// 'this' refers to the 'element' in 'arr.forEach(element.....)' (see below)
// display elements consequently    
inputDisplay.textContent += this.value;     
}
```

instead you should also check for operator and replace in if-statement :

```
if (!symbols.includes(this.value)) {
// 'this' refers to the 'element' in 'arr.forEach(element.....)' (see below)
// display elements consequently    
   let lastChar= inputDisplay.textContent.length && inputDisplay.textContent.length >0 ?inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length] : '';

   if(mathSymbols.includes(this.value)&& mathSymbols.includes(lastChar)){
      inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length]=this.value;
   }
   else{
inputDisplay.textContent += this.value;     
   }
}
```

Only written on phone, so please excuse typos!

Edit:

I've used one of your attempts, because replacing didn't work with index of last character. Furthermore, it's ...length-1, which can be seen in the new version:

```
if (!symbols.includes(this.value) ) {
    // 'this' refers to the 'element' in 'arr.forEach(element.....)' (see below)
       let lastChar = inputDisplay.textContent.length && inputDisplay.textContent.length > 0 ? inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length-1] : '';
     console.log('inputDisplay.textContent.length: ' + inputDisplay.textContent.length);
     //console.log('last char: ' + lastChar);
       if (inputDisplay.textContent.length>0 && mathSymbols.includes(this.value) && mathSymbols.includes(lastChar)) {
          //inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length-1] = this.value; 
         let stringWithoutLastCharacter = inputDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
inputDisplay.textContent = stringWithoutLastCharacter + this.value;
        // console.log('lastCharacter: '+ inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length-1]);
           //console.log('this value: ' + this.value);     
       } else {
           // display elements consequently  
        inputDisplay.textContent += this.value; 
        // console.log('else, this value: ' + this.value);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your responce. This part 'inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length]' was very useful.

Comment: But, it's still not working. I console.logged several items and that's what I got: a) when I press 1: inputDisplay.textContent.length: 0, lastChar: , else, this value: 1; b) then I press +: inputDisplay.textContent.length: 1, lastChar: undefined, else, this value: +; c) then I press -:  inputDisplay.textContent.length: 2, lastChar: undefined, else, this value: -;

Comment: @an_bozh I‘ve realized, that I indeed have a typo. I‘ll edit as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you. This block of code `if (mathSymbols.includes(this.value) && mathSymbols.includes(lastChar)) {
      inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length] = this.value;            
   }` does not work, because **'lastChar'** variable is either ' ', or _undefined_. **mathSymbols** == ['+', '-', '*', '/']. Thank you for your help. I've already learned some interesting and useful things from your answer.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by the first **inputDisplay.textContent.length** in `let lastChar = inputDisplay.textContent.length && inputDisplay.textContent.length > 0 ? inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length-1] : '';` ? I removed it and the code is still working: `let lastChar = inputDisplay.textContent.length > 0 ? inputDisplay.textContent[inputDisplay.textContent.length-1] : '';` I just wanted to know, if it's not the same as **inputDisplay.textContent.length > 0**

Comment: @an_bozh the first is whether it is not undefined, null, or any other falsy value...this is how Javascript works. If the value was undefined, you'll get an Error when trying to access length.